Does MongoDB discard and delete a batch from memory after being loaded and processed?
Actually I was trying to learn about the behavior of itcount() method and the impact of its behavior on the time that it takes to respond.
I thought that after using itcount(), at the end, all the documents are loaded in the memory. I asked Copilot about it and it responded me this way:

Not exactly. The itcount() method processes documents in batches, so
at no point are all documents loaded into memory simultaneously.
Instead, documents are loaded, processed, and then discarded from
memory as the cursor iterates through the collection.
When using itcount(), a specific batch of documents is loaded into
memory, processed (i.e., counted), and then discarded from memory
before the next batch is loaded. This process continues until all
documents have been iterated over and counted. This approach helps
manage memory usage efficiently by not loading all documents into
memory at once.

are these statements valid?
I could not find any valid sources to validate its statement about discarding a batch from memory before the next batch is loaded.
I want to know that is it possible to discard and delete a batch after being loaded and processed by MongoDB?
So, unlike toArray(), which loaded all documents into the memory at the same time, itcount() makes the cursor to iterate all the documents, but does not load all the documents into the memory at once. am I right?
